# mysql - Column count doesn't match value count at row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

error:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username', '$password', 
    '$icq', '$email', '$ip', now(), 'NULL', 0, 0.00, 0, '$ip',
    '0', '0', 0, 0,'0','0','$plainpw')") or die (mysql_error());
```

user Table:

```
INSERT INTO  `store`.`users` (
`username` ,
`password` ,
`icq` ,
`email` ,
`ips` ,
`regdate` ,
`lastlogin` ,
`failedlogin` ,
`balance` ,
`checkercredits` ,
`lastip` ,
`amount_purchased` ,
`amount_refunds` ,
`admin` ,
`banned`
)
VALUES (
'test',  'test',  '44444',  '4444@email.com',  '127.0.0.1',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0',  '0'
);
```

Comment: And the structure of your users table is?

Comment: And what you dont understand?? It says that column count doesnt match so...?

Comment: You specified values for 19 columns in your `INSERT` statement, but the number of columns in your `users` table is not 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering too few, or too many values. Count the number of columns in your table, and check that against the number of values you're attempting to insert.

Answer (score 1):

`Mysql` extension is deprecated.use the `Mysqli` or `PDO` extensions. Please Check the count of columns in your table.

Example for `PDO_Mysql`

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
    VALUES(:fname, :sname, :age)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "fname" => "text",
    "sname" => "text",
    "age" => "18"
));
```

You will get clearly which columns you are missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are tryin to insert 19 values into a table that has 15 columns... So make sure its the right table or that you are inserting the right values.